# creating new dataframe from wrapped array scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe similar to following:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
|left                                 |right               |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray(1)]                    |[WrappedArray(2)]   |
|[WrappedArray(1)]                    |[WrappedArray(2, 3)]|
|[WrappedArray(1), WrappedArray(2, 3)]|[WrappedArray(2)]   |
|[WrappedArray(1), WrappedArray(2, 3)]|[WrappedArray(2, 1)]|
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to create another dataframe as follows:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
|left                                 |right               |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
|1                                    |2                   |
|1                                    |2*3                 |
|1&2*2                                |2                   |
|1&2*3                                |2*3                 |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Here elements of array are separated by `&` and elements of inner array is separated by `*`.

For example:

```
[WrappedArray(1,2,34), WrappedArray(2, 3)]

1*2,34&2*3
```

Comment: It is not about converting to string. I need to do some regex to replace few things inside array. I am new to scala spark

Comment: You can't execute `regexp_replace` on an array. You need to use concat_ws to convert it to string or write a UDF if your requirement is more complex, as explained in the duplicate.